# Autowiring doesn't work in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, generics, inversion-of-control

I have the following source example which works in Spring 3.2.6 but doesn't work in 4.0.1

```
public interface RunTest<T extends Number> {
void run(T number);

}

public class BasicRunTest implements RunTest<Integer>{

@Override
public void run(Integer number) {
}

}

@Component
public class BeanTest  {
@Autowired
private RunTest<Number> runTest; 
}
```

If I run the application I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.test.RunTest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Can you show us your context configuration? Do you have a `RunTest` bean defined anywhere?

Comment: Would this help you [spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/)

Answer (score 5):

It is a new [Spring Feature: Spring now treats generic types as a form of qualifier when injecting Beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-generics-as-qualifiers) - or in other words: autowire pay attention to the generic type!

You have `BasicRunTest implements RunTest<Integer>` (Integer) and ask spring for `@Autowire prive RunTest<Number> runTest;` (Number) - that is not compatible!

try

```
private RunTest<? extends Number> runTest;
```

*(That it worked with Spring 3.x, is more or less a bug, because your code break the generic constraint)*

Comment: @user3249497: the common way in stack overflow to say "Thank you", is to accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/about)